# What's the latest version of Rails 2.3.x?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

[rubyforge](http://rubyforge.org/frs/?group_id=307) is out-dated. When can I get the latest version number of Rails 2.3.x? I'd like to use 2.3.x for a while before upgrading to [latest](http://rubyonrails.org/download) 3.x of Rails.

Comment: Suggest you to use 2.3.5, because next versions until latest 2.3.9 release have some bugs (and also a bug fixes, but mostly bugs), e.g. nested attributes and form bugs. Look http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2010/9/4/ruby-on-rails-2-3-9-released for more information, at least 3 bugs already found in critical elements like forms, cookies...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
$ gem list -ra rails | grep 'rails ('

*** REMOTE GEMS ***

rails (3.2.3, 2.3.14, 2.3.13 ...)

$ gem install rails -v 2.3.13
```

Comment: That gives a big list of gems containing "rails" in their names. I use `gem list -ra rails | grep 'rails ('`.

Answer (score 4):

**[Rubygems.org says it all](http://rubygems.org/gems/rails/versions)**

Also, you can always tell by the list of tags in the [github repo](http://github.com/rails/rails).